# How to get information from asp dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ViewBag with 'kenmerken'  :

```
while (reader.Read())
  ViewBag.Kenmerken.Add(new SelectListItem { 
  value = reader.GetString(0),
  Text = reader.GetString(0)
});
Reader.Close();
```

And a form using aps.net razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("KenmerkSelectie2", "KenmerkSelectie", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "kenmerk2" }))
{
  @Html.DropDownList("Kenmerken", (SelectList)ViewBag.Kenmerken, 
  "-- Selecteer        een kenmerk--", 
  new{
      onchange = "document.getElementById('kenmerk2').submit();"
     });
}
```

And a httppost method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KenmerkSelectie2(string value)
{
   var foo = ViewBag.Kenmerk;
   var foo2 = value;
   var foo3 = ViewBag.Kenmerken;
   return View();
}
```

Every foo is null, How do I get the selected value?

Comment: `ViewBag` is for passing data from the controller to the view (not from the view to a controller)

Comment: ViewBag is not saved between postbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given the name of the field `Kenmerken`, yet your `HttpPost` method expects a value called `value`, change either of those to match.

You should **seriously** consider creating a model though for this, something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
@model MyViewModel

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.Values, 
     "-- Selecteer        een kenmerk--", new{
  onchange = "document.getElementById('kenmerk2').submit();"
 })
```

Also, while you're at it, extract that inline JavaScript out.

Comment: Oh wow that was easy... THX ! i'm searching for readable documentation about asp forms..

Comment: @user3432681 No problems glad I could help. Moving over from Web forms is a big change, but stuff becomes so much easier when you know how :). I would take a look at using models and maybe do some tutorials on it because that'll make things much easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

**First issues**

---

Viewbag is only for passing the data between the controller and view

---

**second issues**

---

You need to give the  name of the select field in parameter of the action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KenmerkSelectie2(string Kenmerken)
{
   var foo2 = Kenmerken;
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KenmerkSelectie2(string kenmerken)
{ 
    var foo3 = kenmerken;
    return View();
}
```

but using model binding is a good idea: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

here is the dropdown in your view :

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Kenmerken", (SelectList)ViewBag.kenmerken)
```

Then Jquery script to get the value of your dropdown and put it in your ActionResult post

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('Kenmerken').change(function(){
        var value = $('Kenmerken').val();
        var url = YourControllerName/KenmerkSelectie2
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            cache:false,
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                MyDropDownValue : value
            },
            success: function()
            {

            }
        })
     });
  });
```

and your actionResult :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KenmerkSelectie2(string MyDropDownValue)
{
   var foo4 = MyDropDownValue //here    
   var foo = ViewBag.Kenmerk;
   var foo2 = value;
   var foo3 = ViewBag.Kenmerken;
   return View();
}
```